# Convert default/offline to online profile?

Tags: la-noire

I started my game in L.A. Noire with an default/offline account.

Is there any way to convert it to an online account in Rockstar Social Club without losing my saved progress?
Can you maybe move the savegame files somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is straight from Rockstar's website. The short answer is no, you need to have separate accounts and there is no way to migrate an offline account to an online one.

Source of information is here: http://support.rockstargames.com/entries/20634122-information-about-social-club-accounts-in-l-a-noire

Hope this helps.

Comment: Damn, thanks. Guess I will have to start the game over again.

Comment: Sucks doesn't it. It's the same for quite a few games. I guess a good rule of thumb would be "create an online account" first and foremost and then swap to offline by pulling out the cable or so. Seems like they prevent this now by not allowing you to save though so it's messed up in both ways.

Answer (score 0):

This is a super old question, but I just had the same problem and solved it.

After creating a new social club account, you'll have a new folder in

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Rockstar Games\L.A. Noire\Profiles\
```

The newer folder obviously corresponds to the new online profile. The other folder should contain the save files and prefs.lanoire file from your offline profile. Copy these items to the new online profile folder, overwriting the existing prefs.lanoire file there.

It should go without saying if you make a mistake and copy over the wrong profile for instance, you're gonna have a bad time. Making a quick copy before making changes never hurts.

All your save game data and unlockables should appear in your online profile. You may have to resume your latest save in the new profile just to make sure everything syncs correctly.